# Multiselection between dataviews ExtJS 4.2.2

Tags: extjs

For example I have 5 dataViews with elements (simple rows). Does ability exist to realize multiselection between this dataView (all of this dataViews have different data-stores)? I mean non-algorithmic realization... Of course, I can write some logic to implement this, but maybe some standard solution exist?

Comment: What is your question ? Can DataViews have multi-select ? If it is, then yes they can. Look up the `itemSelector` property in the documentation, and add `multiSelect: true` in your view definition

Comment: Hm, no... Can ExtJS have multi-select between different dataViews? For example, you select one item in dataView1, you press "ctrl", and click on the another item in dataView2, as a result - 2 selected items in different dataViews...

Comment: I don't believe it is possible without custom code, since each dataview has its own selection model. Although, you can select multiple items in each individual view, but they will not be linked together (e.g. clicking an item in dataView2 without Ctrl will not clear selections on other dataViews). I'll try to cook you up something to make it work :)

Comment: oh, no, thank You for proposition, but it is my work =) I just wanted to make sure that any standard ExtJS solution doesn't exist ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, maybe this can work :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.DataViews', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init : function() {
        this.views = {};
        this.listen({
            component: {
                'dataview-1' : {
                    'render' : this.onDataViewRender,
                    'itemclick' : this.onItemClick
                },
                'dataview-2' : {
                    'render' : this.onDataViewRender,
                    'itemclick' : this.onItemClick
                }
            }
        });
    },

    onDataViewRender: function(view){
        this.views[view.getXType()] = view;
    },

    onItemClick: function(view, record, items, index, e){
        //If Ctrl is not pressed when clicking an item, clear the selection of all views before proceeding
        if(!e.ctrlKey)
        {
            Ext.Object.each(this.views, function(xtype, viewObj){
                viewObj.getSelectionModel().deselectAll();
            });
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.DataView1', {
    extend: 'Ext.view.View',
    xtype: 'dataview-1',
    multiSelect: true,
});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.DataView2', {
    extend: 'Ext.view.View',
    xtype: 'dataview-2',
    multiSelect: true,
});
```